# Sum of Random Variables that are not in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

let $X\sim P$ be a real-valued random variable that is not an element of $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ for some $p>0$. Furthermore, let $X_1, \dots, X_N$ represent $i.i.d.$ copies of $X$ and for any $i\in\{1,\dots,N\} $ let $ a_i\in\mathbb{R}$ such that there exist at least one $j\in\{1,\dots,N\} $ such that $a_j \neq 0$.

My question is whether the assertion
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^{N} a_i X_i \not\in L^p(\mathbb{R})
\end{equation}
is true.

All the best,

Carl

Comment: For $p \geq 1$ the answer is YES.

Comment: I believe the proof is highly non-trivial. Do you have a reference or a theorem/lemma which shows this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial answer: let us show that the result is true for $p \geq 1$. For $p=1$ this is a trivial application of Fubini's Theorem, so let us assume that $p>1$.

Lemma

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables with $EX=0=EY$ and $E|X+Y|^{p} <\infty$ then $E|X|^{p} <\infty$ and $E|Y|^{p} <\infty$.

Proof: $E|X+Y|^{p} =\int|x+y|^{p} dF_X(x)dF_Y(y) \geq \int |\int (x+y)dF_Y(y)|^{p}dF_X(x)$ by Jensens's inequality applied to the convex function $x \to x^{p}$. This gives $\int |x|^{p}dF_X(x) <\infty$  since $\int ydF_Y(y)=0$. Simialrly, $\int |y|^{p}dF_Y(y) <\infty$

In our case we can always assume that the mean is $0$ since adding a constant does not change integrability. [Existence of $E|X_i|$ is immediate from an application of Fubini's Theorem since $E|\sum_{i} a_i X_i| <\infty$].  Hence the lemma tells us that $\sum_{i\neq j} a_i X_i \in L^{p}$. If $a_i=0$ for all $i \neq j$ the we already know that $X_j \in L^{p}$ so there is nothing to prove. If some $a_i$ with $i \neq j$ is non-zero we can repeat the argument.

Comment: Thank you very much, Sir. Since we want to show that the sum is not $L^p$ I believe the statement holds only for $p>1$ and not for $p\geq 1$ since we need the existence of the first moment to use this Lemma.

Comment: @Carl Goof comment. I have added one line to the answer to make it correct.